# Can't get Laravel OrderBy date to work in Eloquent statement

Tags: eloquent, sql-order-by, laravel-6, rawsql

I need to pull the records in date order, but having spent hours researching this and trying many approaches and variations in my code, I'm getting nowhere.

I need to sort on the `left_employer_date` field, which is a VARCHAR format. So I'm trying to convert the VARCHAR to DATE format to enable a date-based sort.

Here's my data:

```
Employer name,  Position held,  Hire date,  Left employer date
```

---

```
Harteman Boat Yards,    Foreman,    01/22/1998, 05/23/2005        
Portland Light Rail Services,   Shift Manager,  08/01/2005, 12/31/2018    
US Forest Service,  Game Warden,    01/12/2019, 04/23/2017
```

Here's my controller code to pull this data into a collection in left_employer_date order:

```
$employment_info = EmploymentHistory::orderBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(left_employer_date, \"%m/%d/%Y\")"), 'DESC')->get();
```

I've tried this in many variations and always get the returned data in the order entered (shown above), not sorted by date. Seems like no matter what I try, the `orderBy` is ignored.

My project is Laravel 6 on NGINX with MariaDB

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DATE_FORMAT transform a date to a string
Tryp the inverse 'STR_TO_DATE(str,format)'

More docs https://mariadb.com/kb/en/str_to_date/

Comment: Thank you, that worked (once I removed the quotes off the field name). Can't believe the answer was staring me in the face all this time!